# Docker Nginx with mount on /tmp/example

Tags: linux, docker

im trying to mount nginx image to `/tmp/example` and on my sample site im getting 403 error.

Im running it with command:

`docker run --rm --name test-nginx -v /tmp/example:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8080:80 nginx`

When i mount to any other directory for example /home/user/ im getting to my website without any issue. I found out in logs this error while trying to reach site:

`[error] 29#29: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/                    " is forbidden`

I've tried to `chmod` directory to 777 but that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the /tmp/example folder exist on your host directory with your sample site that you want to load into the nginx /usr/share/nginx/html location in the container. If the example folder is not present it will create a folder with root user when you volume mount that non existent folder using docker command and you get a 403 error because the container is launched with not root user.

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/example/
$ touch /tmp/example/hello.html
$ echo "hello" > /tmp/example/hello.html 
$ docker run -d --rm --name test-nginx -v /tmp/example/:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8080:80 nginx 
84e5e49d7460051dc6ba624176ab66d38209b015be3e80f7f42ca5c71308f9ab
$ docker exec -it 84e5e49d7460 sh
root@84e5e49d7460:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html/
root@84e5e49d7460:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls -ltr
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 1001 6 Apr 25 12:14 hello.html
```

The file that gets volume mounted is with the same user id and group as it is present on the host machine.
access your application - http://<host_fqdn>:8080/hello.html

Comment: I had created dir and file before running, but i rerun this like you said and still im getting 403 error

Comment: check the ownership of the files within the container /usr/share/nginx/html/ if they are with root user. Also the ownership of the example directory on the host machine